# web login using VBA

Tags: html, css, excel, vba

I'm trying to access my webtext a/c using VBA.
The first step is trying to get the tag for the username and password input boxes.

I've used inspect elements to determine the tags and I think they are
"username" and "password".  However, this does not work. Unfortunately, I've no experience of CSS.

Here is my code.

```
Sub MyLogin()

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://www.o2online.ie/o2/login/"
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .document.all.Item("username").Value = "MyUsername"
        .document.all.Item("password").Value = "MyPassword"
        .document.forms(1).submit
    End With

End Sub
```

Any help appreciated.

Regards, Rueful

Comment: don't you need to have this submit line: `.document.forms(1).submit`??

Comment: That allows me to click the login button but the username and password are still blank. I'll correct the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the login form is inside iframe it may not allow to access the control directly.

Try below code

```
Sub MyLogin()

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://www.o2online.ie/idm/login/lightBoxLogin.jsp?authn_try_count=0&contextType=external&username"

        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        .document.all.Item("username").Value = "MyUsername"
        .document.all.Item("password").Value = "MyPassword"
        .document.forms(0).submit
        .Navigate "http://www.o2online.ie/o2/login/"
    End With

End Sub
```