# Input text into html input box using vba

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to input a value into a from on an internet explorer page using VBA.  I have seen similar posts but can't seem to pinpoint my problem.  I am somewhat fluent with VBA but HTML is new to me.  The ID attributes change on the webpage I am accessing every time you load the page.  Here is a shot of the HTML element I am trying to access:

```
<input type="text" size="20" style="text-align: right; width: 261px;" autocomplete="off"    id="ext-comp-1067" name="user_numbers.1.number_1" class="x-form-text x-form-field x-form- num-field" title="">
```

The code I am currently using is here:

```
    Sub OpenWebPage()

    Dim ObjCollection As Object
   Dim i As Long
Dim objElement As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim form As Object



    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
    ie.Navigate "http://11.182.123.21/#!/view/dashboards/dashboard-1"
    ie.Visible = True
    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
   Wend


    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

 Set ObjCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByName("user_numbers.1.number_1").Value = "123"

End sub
```

The name "user_number.1.number_1" I think is the only element in the html that I can use to find this input box, the ID changes every time you open the webpage.
How do I got about entering a value in this field?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the ID also change `id="ext-comp-1067"`?

Comment: Yes, it changes whenever you close the webpage and reload it.  The name  does not change though that is why I am trying to use it.

Comment: you have an extra "=" sign.

Comment: I tried the exact same code and it works for me.
BTW which Internet Explorer version is installed on your machine?

Comment: @PradeepKumar  I am using IE 8

Comment: ok.. I tried on IE9. Is it possible for you to upgrade to IE9 and test? Though as far as I know, this should not matter.

Comment: Sorry.. "exact same code" means the code after implementing suggestions in my reply.

Answer (score 5):

As sid mentioned, you have an extra "=" sign.

Replace

```
Set ObjCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByName("user_numbers.1.number_1").Value = "123"
```

with

```
ie.Document.getElementsByName("user_numbers.1.number_1")(0).Value = "123"
```

This is just off my head and not tested code. If this doesn't work replace `(0)` in the above code with `(1)`.

If there is no other element on the page with the same name then this will work.
Otherwise replace `(0)` in the above statement with appropriate ordinal position.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to take out the extra "=" sign, that was part of something different I was trying. @pradeep Kumar, I tried as you mentioned above with still no luck.  I am getting "runtime error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set".  And thank you both for your Input!

Comment: I am trying the same code above and am still coming up with the same error.  "Object Variable or with block variable not set".

Comment: It could be possible that the html tag you are looking at is not in the intenet explorer main window, but inside another frame or iframe. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

How about finding the ID everytime like this

```
my_var = ie.doc.body.innerhtml

pos_1 = instr(1, my_var, "user_numbers.1.number_1", vbTextCompare)
pos_2 = InStrRev(my_var, "id", pos_1, vbTextCompare)
pos_3 = instr(pos_2, my_var, "name", vbTextCompare)

my_id = mid(my_var, 3+pos_2, (-1+pos_3) - (3+pos_2)
```

now try

```
ie.Document.getElementById(my_id).Value = "123"
```

I can't get access to your url, so you might have to tweak the numbers added and subtracted in the "mid" function

Comment: Ron, I am afraid this is a bit over my head.  I am not sure how to go about using the code you posted.  I see what you are trying to accomplish though.  How would I define all the new variables introduced?    Also, any ideas on why this code doesn't work?  The name is unique and I cannot write into the input box.                                     'Code' ie.Document.getElementsByName("user_numbers.1.number_1")(0).Value = "123"  'Code'

Comment: Also, I am new here and cannot figure out how to post the code nicely in separate boxes when adding a comment.  Any help there would also be great. Thanks!

Comment: No need to define the new variables.  Just try putting my code after your "Application.Wait" line.  Step through the code using F8 and see if you get the desired ID.  "InStr" finds the numeric position of the first character in the search term (like "ID") in my_var (which in this case contains the source code behind the web page).  InStrRev does the same in reverse (see Excel VBA help for correct syntax and a better explanation).  So we're just using the pos_1, _2 and _3 to locate the position of "ID" in the source code.  Next we use "mid" to extract the actual ID from the source code.

Comment: at pos_2 I get an "invalid procedure or argument" error.  I am playing around with the inStrRev function, but nothing has been a success.

Comment: did you get a non-zero value for pos_1?

Comment: I bet my_var is empty, use my_var = ie.document.body.innerhtml

Comment: That is what I used, My_var is not empty.  I am trouble shooting now trying to see what is going on.

Comment: for whatever reason I cannot find this string with your code in pos_1 "User_numbers.1.number_1".  I tried this with some different text in the HTML and it finds it just fine.  Any thoughts?  Thank you very much for all of your help by the way.

Comment: Are there other occurrences of "user_numbers"; if you put "user_numbers" in pos_1 does that work? Is "ID" always of the form "ext-comp-ABCD"?  If so, search for "ext-comp-" or something similar.  I can't get to your website to check it out myself.  Sounds like some of the other guys responding to your question were able to get there - wonder why I can't?  In any case, this technique has worked for me when I was dealing with a ID that was always changing.

Comment: No one else would be able to reach the site.  They must have tried the same code with a different site.  It is a local Device on our network, you have to be plugged into the network to access it.  It is the only occurrence of the "User_numbers".  I have tried searching other text in the HTML and have found it, it is only that text I cannot find, which is probably why my original method did not work as well.  As for the ID; that ID for that input is always in that format, I will try that

Comment: I think something more than just being able to find the correct name or ID is going on.  Even if I keep the same window open and try to write to the box using the ID given for that instance I still get errors "object variables or with block variables not set".  Anyway I know you cannot reach the site so it is a little difficult to trouble shoot so thanks for the help!  If anything else strikes you please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean the line ie.Document.getElementById("correct id").Value = "123" doesn't work when you manually insert the correct ID?

Comment: Maybe you're examining the wrong line of HTML.  Examine every item on the web page and see which one puts "123" in the target.                                                                     numb = ie.Document.all.Length - 1
        On Error Resume Next
        For x = 0 To numb
           ie.document.all.item(x).value = "123"
        Next
Then you can use stuff like                                         a = ie.Document.all.Item(x).innerhtml
      b = ie.Document.all.Item(x).Name
      c = ie.Document.all.Item(x).ID
to identify the item(x) that successfully put "123" in the box.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did as you suggested and it turns out I cannot access anything inside the <i frame> element in  the HTML code.  Not sure what the even means or why I can't access inside it but that seems to be the problem, as that is where the input box I need to get to is located.

Comment: Aha, an IFrame!  To get the HTML inside the iframe, extract the src attribute from the <iframe > tag and navigate to the URL formed by that src and the base URL.  Then constructions like you've been trying can be used.  See also
 http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?40649-Automating-IE-to-get-data-from-a-website     and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470634/web-login-using-vba

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help.  I will let you know how this turns out!