# How to use getElementsByTagName("input") if "type" is hidden

Tags: html, vba, getelementsbytagname

VBA Code I am using:

```
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLInputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set HTMLInputs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each HTMLInput In HTMLInputs
HTMLInput.innerText = Cells(z, s)
Next HTMLInput
```

HTML Code from the website:

```
<input name="description" id="description" type="hidden" value="" vld="0" md="dt|STRING||em|Bitte geben Sie eine Beschreibung ein.||gdn|description">
```

I am not able to write the content from the Excel sheet to the HTML text box on the Website and I assume it doesn't work because type="hidden"

If there are any further explanation needed please let me know.

Comment: What's the issue with what you have?

Comment: HTML Code from the Website: <input name="description" id="description" type="hidden" value="" vld="0" md="dt|STRING||em|Bitte geben Sie eine Beschreibung ein.||gdn|description">

Comment: I am not able to write the content from the Excel sheet to the HTML text box on the Website and I assume it doesn´t work because type="hidden"

Comment: Have you tried `.getElementByID` using `description` as the ID?  What are `HTMLInput` defined as?  Are they populated?

Comment: Yes I tried ByID, but didn´t work as well. HTMLInput is declared: Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement,
Dim HTMLInputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Comment: "I am not able to write the content from the Excel sheet to the HTML text box" ... so set the textbox's 'Value' and not the inner text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input text into html input box using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611714/input-text-into-html-input-box-using-vba)

Comment: HTMLInput.value doesn´t work either. With the a.m. Code I can write in any TextBox on the Website expect for the one I posted the HTML Code. The only difference from the other HTML codes is the type="hidden"

Comment: Any further advices?